# Unround iOS simulator corners in Big Sur?

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator, macos-big-sur

In macOS Big Sur, is there a way to remove the rounded corners from the iOS Simulator windows? I'm not looking to change this setting system-wide, just for the simulator.

Why? For older simulators like iPhone 8 and older iPads, the rounded corners in the non-bezel windows clip part of what the end user would see. It's small, but it matters in my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Window > Show Device Bezels so that it is checked. Now the simulated screen display is a rectangle without rounding.

[image]

Comment: Thank you , I was hoping there'd be a way without adding the bezels.

Comment: Also - you're my favorite technical writer!!